# Multiple Versions of Cached Controller Actions in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, caching

I'm looking for a basic sanity check on what I'm trying to do in CakePHP: essentially I have a page which displays news articles, but the functionality has recently been upgraded so that different news articles may be displayed to users in different geographical zones.

What I'd like is to have a different cached version of each page per zone, but I'm not sure whether this will be easy to implement within Cake, or if it would be fighting against my framework.

It seems to me from the documentation that calling Cache::Read/Cache::Write passing some kind of zone identifier as the $key parameter might do the trick, but ideally I'd like to keep using the CacheHelper.  Is there for instance anything I could add into the $cacheAction configuration options to sort this out?

Obviously I'm going to roll my sleeves up and try to find a solution, but it's always nice to check if someone has done this kind of thing before, or knows immediately how to get it done...

Comment: You should always mention your exact cakehp version.

Comment: If you take a look at [2.3 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html) you will see that you might be able to leverage the new "prefix" option ("has been added to core.php to allow multiple domains/languages per setup") for your cache issue. timezones as prefixes so to speak.

Comment: @mark Yeah, that's a good policy.  I was a bit embarrassed as this application is still in the dark ages of Cake 1.2!  If Cake 2 provides awesome new functionality then that could be a great excuse for getting round to the upgrade.

Comment: It's quite possible of course that the correct approach would be to insist on having different unique urls for different content...